# SQLite Insert with the newly generated id

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with an auto increment field and another field `VARCHAR` filed. I would like to fill the string field with the newly generated id directly in the insert query. For example with table:

```
Person
(
    id auto_increment, 
    name varchar
)
```

I would like to perform a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO Person(name) VALUE ('Person #' + ROWID())
```

Anyway to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will use the last inserted row id with the increment of 1 to generate the next person id. **Keep in mind that for `last_insert_rowid()` you should not be doing concurrent inserts to the database.**

```
INSERT INTO Person (name) SELECT 'Person #' || (last_insert_rowid()+1);
```

Alternatively this will read the biggest ID you currently have and increment +1 to it and then concatenate it with the text. If it returns null it uses 1.

```
INSERT INTO Person (name) SELECT 'Person #' || (IFNULL((MAX(id)+1),1)) FROM Person LIMIT 1;
```

This one will get the index of autoincrement:

```
INSERT INTO Person (name) SELECT 'Person #' || (seq+1) FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name="person"
```

You can also do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Person (name) VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO Person (name) VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO Person (name) VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO Person (name) VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO Person (name) VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO Person (name) VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO Person (name) VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO Person (name) VALUES (NULL);
UPDATE Person SET name = 'Person #' || id WHERE name IS NULL;
```

Or:

```
INSERT INTO Person (name) VALUES ('Person');
UPDATE Person SET name = name || ' #' || id WHERE id = last_insert_rowid();
```

This one will update the names that does not have a `#` with its row id:

```
INSERT INTO Person (name) VALUES ('Person');
INSERT INTO Person (name) VALUES ('Person');
INSERT INTO Person (name) VALUES ('Person');
INSERT INTO Person (name) VALUES ('Person');
UPDATE Person SET name = name || ' #' || id WHERE (LENGTH(name)-LENGTH(REPLACE(name, '#', ''))) = 0;
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/20d83/2/0)

Comment: Thank you! Actually, i was looking for a method without update or select, but since it's seems to be not possible, i will use the update way, which is i think the safest.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't store the same info twice. Just generate the string you want dynamically when you query:

```
SELECT name || '#' || id FROM Person
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do two sentences: INSERT + UPDATE, you cannot access the last insert id in the current insert sentence

Answer (score 1):

The system will not reliably know that `ID` until the row is inserted.  I would think the best solution would be a view (since SQLite does not support computed columns which would be the easiest route).  Just insert the `VARCHAR` and use a view to build the concatenated value at request time using the inserted `VARCHAR` and the allocated `ID`.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

This will not be guranteed but this might work ...

```
INSERT INTO tab1(val) VALUES ('tab1 #' + cast((SELECT top 1 IDENT_CURRENT('tab1') + IDENT_INCR('tab1') FROM tab1) as varchar(20)))
```